# Function pointer variable function call triggers another function. Possible in C

Tags: c

I have a function like this:

```
void abc1(){
   printf("hello abc1\n");
}
```

Another function like this:

```
void abc2(){
   printf("hello abc2\n");
}
```

And a function pointer defination in same program

```
void (*abc)();
```

in main I have something like this

```
void main(){
   abc = abc1;
   abc();     //prints hello abc1
}
```

Is there a way in C  that I can link `abc2` with `abc` function pointer so as if abc assigned function (which is `abc1`) is called so my `abc2` is also get executed. Any possibility? `abc2` called at the call of `abc()`?

Comment: You mean you want to do `abc=abc2; abc();`?

Comment: @dbush And also abc1 possible?

Comment: You can assign to a function pointer just like any other variable and subsequently use it.

Comment: @dbush then will it point to both abc1 and abc2

Comment: Like any variable, it can only hold one value at a time.  If you want to call both functions, you need to create a wrapper function for that and assign it to `abc`.

Comment: @dbush what about trap handlers? Can trap handler runs at function call

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Please tell us which problem you are _actually_ trying to resolve.

Comment: I want abc2 triggered when `abc=abc1` called. That's what asked

Comment: But *why* do you want that?  What problem are you trying to solve by having the ability to do so?

Comment: Linked list or stack of function pointers, and call each function in order. You decide FIFO or LIFO order. Maybe best to use doubly-linked list, and decide direction. I have answered elsewhere how to implement linked list :-)

Comment: I dont want to call next. How abc will be called

Comment: You write: _"I want abc2 triggered when abc=abc1 called."_. It's unclear why you need to do this, but if I understood your requirement I'd say: no, there is no way `abc2` gets called magically during the assignment `abc=abc1`.

Comment: @jabberwocky ok